# Subsetting lists after split in R

Tags: r, csv, split, dataframe

here's the issue

I have a csv file which I read.csv(), and prints to this:

```
   grp  b a  id d c
1 grp1  2 1 id3 3 2
2 grp1 -2 1 id1 3 2
3 grp0 -2 1 id4 3 2
4 grp0  1 1 id0 3 2
5 grp0  1 1 id2 3 2
```

Now I want to split this into two dataframes, one with data for `grp1` and another for `grp2`

```
groups <- split(raw, raw$grp);
```

Which yields this:

```
$grp0
   grp  b a  id d c
3 grp0 -2 1 id4 3 2
4 grp0  1 1 id0 3 2
5 grp0  1 1 id2 3 2

$grp1
   grp  b a  id d c
1 grp1  2 1 id3 3 2
2 grp1 -2 1 id1 3 2
```

Now I just want the `a,b,c,d` rows from each of these lists, so I need to coerce them to dataframes to use `subset()`, which means I need to:

```
for(i in 1:length(groups))
{
      x <- subset(as.data.frame(groups[i]), select = c(a,b,c,d));
      some_function(x); 
}
```

Problem is, when I do this, it says *column a does not exist*, and when I print this stuff out, this is what we see:

```
 grp0.grp grp0.b grp0.a grp0.id grp0.d grp0.c
3     grp0     -2      1     id4      3      2
4     grp0      1      1     id0      3      2
5     grp0      1      1     id2      3      2
  grp1.grp grp1.b grp1.a grp1.id grp1.d grp1.c
1     grp1      2      1     id3      3      2
2     grp1     -2      1     id1      3      2
```

So these columns are no longer just a,b,c,d but their name prepended by the name created during the split. Is their a way I can avoid this happening? Or is there a way to get the name of the dataframe and prepend it to the list of elements I am subsetting? I just want to end up with dataframes that look something like this, the column names need not be exact:

```
$grp0
       b  a  d c
    3 -2  1  3 2
    4  1  1  3 2
    5  1  1  3 2

$grp1
       b  a  d c
    1  2  1  3 2
    2 -2  1  3 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the future, please use dput() on any object that you want to present to us, so we don't have to manually type in your example to write the code.

Are you a SAS programmer? You don't need semicolons after every line...

```
raw <- data.frame(
    grp=c("grp1","grp1","grp0","grp0","grp0"),
    b=c(2,-2,2,1,1),
    a=rep(1,5),
    id=c("id3","id1","id4","id0","id2"),
    d=rep(3,5),
    c=rep(2,5)
)
groups <- split(raw, raw$grp)
```

You were actually pretty close. 
I'd recommend reading up on the difference between `` ?`[` `` and `` ?`[[` ``. Here's your corrected code:

```
x <- list()
for(i in 1:length(groups)) {       
x[[i]] <- subset(as.data.frame(groups[[i]]), select = c(a,b,c,d));     
  } 
names(x) <- names(groups)
x
```

With that said, please try to learn the ?lapply functions

```
lapply(groups, function(.groups) .groups[,c("a","b","c","d")])
```

Comment: you could do it in one fell swoop: `split(raw[, c("a","b","c","d")], raw$grp)`  Nice answer; very thorough +1

Comment: So after I split, I have some list x which I will assign my groups after I have subsetted them. Then I will just move the names on over after the loop finishes. 

Here's the issue, I will be passing the values of x into a function which needs a data frame. When I use is.data.frame(x[i]), I get false, and when I coerce x[i] into a dataframe, I end up with same problem of badly named columns. Am I misunderstanding something here?

So we've solved the subsetting issue, but not the renaming issue

Comment: try `is.data.frame(x[[i]])` The issue you're having is that you don't understand that when you have a list, `x`, subsetting `x` with `x[1]` will return a list with one element, (ie, the first element of x). Compare to `x[[1]]` which will just return the first element of x.  As a general rule of thumb, when working with lists, you want to use `` `[[` `` to extract a single element  and `` `[` `` when you want more than one element of the list (still in list form--ie, `x[1:3]`.

Comment: And it works like a charm! Alright, guess I really need to have a look at [[]] then. Thanks so much!

Comment: +1 - also, no need to create a function, you can do `lapply(groups, "[", c("a", "b", "c", "d"))`